# Find all aliases for a given node

Tags: path-aliases

I'm currently working with a client and running some scripts to generate reports (orphaned pages, etc). Right now, I need a way to get all possible registered aliases for a node. Right now, I'm using

```
$node = node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE);
$nurl = 'node/' . $nid;
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias($nurl);
```

I'm realizing, though, that the client has more than several pages where multiple aliases lead to the same node. Is there a function to retrieve an array of possible aliases?

Thanks!

Comment: There is PROBABLY a module to do this, but I've never looked for one. Hell, it seems to me there may even be a way that's built in to core to do this... but again, I've never seen it in my travels. If I was going to do this, I'd do it using: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7 ... the $node object will have the Drupal URL. You should be able to query url_alias.source for a any matching "alias" results.

Comment: I've created a module to show all URL aliases for a given page:
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/artem.kolotilkin/2503121 Check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a database query

```
$aliases = db_query('
  SELECT alias
  FROM {url_alias}
  WHERE source = :source
', array(':source' => 'node/' . $nid))->fetchAll();
```

You may need to modify things a little if you have a multilingual site to take the `language` column into account.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I had planned on doing unless someone else came up with a better answer :D