# How do I get all the aliases defined for a route?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I want to get all the path aliases defined for a route. Using [`AliasStorage::lookupPathAlias()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21AliasStorage.php/function/AliasStorage%3A%3AlookupPathAlias/8.2.x) or [`AliasManager::getAliasByPath()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21AliasManager.php/function/AliasManager%3A%3AgetAliasByPath/8.2.x), I get a single path alias, even when there are more path aliases defined for that route.

If I were using Drupal 7, I would use the answers given to [Find all aliases for a given node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115437).

How can I get all the path aliases defined for a single route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same as in Drupal 7, because there is no API to return multiple aliases for a single source path, so your only option, if you really need that (I guess there is a reason that you are not using redirects), is a custom query, which is the same as in 7.x, with the only difference that it has a leading /.

So, copied from the other issue:

```
$aliases = \Drupal::database()->query('
  SELECT alias
  FROM {url_alias}
  WHERE source = :source
', array(':source' => '/node/' . $nid))->fetchAll();
```